# How to add top level element using Linq to XML

Tags: c#-4.0, linq-to-xml

Assuming I have a xdocument called xd, with the following xml already created.

```
<Alert>
  <Source>
    <DetectTime>12:03:2010 12:22:21</DetectTime>
  </Source>
</Alert>
```

How would I be able to add another Alert element, such that the xml becomes:

```
<Alert>
  <Source>
    <DetectTime>12:03:2010 12:22:21</DetectTime>
  </Source>
</Alert>
<Alert>
</Alert>
```

Adding an additional  elements seems to be fairly easy, but when adding in a top level element it excepts.

Comment: Could you show us the code you are using to add the top level node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your desired XML structure is invalid; you need a root element in order to add another "Alert" node. The following code shows how to add it when a root node exists:

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(@"<root>
    <Alert>
    <Source>
        <DetectTime>12:03:2010 12:22:21</DetectTime>
    </Source>
    </Alert>
</root>");
xdoc.Root.Add(new XElement("Alert"));
Console.WriteLine(xdoc);
```

The above code produces `<Alert />` since no child nodes are added to it (this will change once you add to it). If you want the closing tag as you have shown you can use `xdoc.Root.Add(new XElement("Alert", String.Empty));` instead.

To verify that your desired output has an invalid structure you can try parsing it using `XDocument.Parse` similar to what I've shown above.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Ahmad. The xml I have is being generated dynamically, i.e. on the fly. Static blocks like that are out the window. Its did report an exception, when I tried to add another <Alert> element.

Comment: So it only seems to work if their is an enclosing element above the element your trying to enter.

Comment: @scope_creep I'm not sure what your end goal is, but one thought is to concatenate the `<root>` and `</root>` tags to your XML, add the elements you need, then use LINQ to do your work and finally extract all `Alert` nodes out as a string. Again, not sure what your goal is but this would ultimately get you a string with the XML structure you want. Is that something you would be interested in doing?